Not able to find and click item in a dropdown using Selenium
Having hard time to find and click an item in dropdown using selenium.
I am able to click dropdown, and it shows the items, I want to click 2nd item "Standard".
Here is the HTML
<md-option ng-value="DocumentTypeObject" ng-repeat="DocumentTypeObject in DocumentTypeList |orderBy : 'name'" title="Standard" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_609" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]" style="">
  <div class="md-text ng-binding"> Standard </div>
  <div class="md-ripple-container" style=""></div>
</md-option>

Here how it looks like in UI:
enter image description here
Here is my code:
TT = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//md-option[contains(.,'Standard')]"))
TT.Click()

I get error no such element found
Xpath in html looks like this (dynamic for every iteration)

xpath=//div[11]/md-select-menu/md-content/md-option[2]

this //di[11] keeps changing for every new object i look for and iterate.
Any help please?
Able to find and click but not working

Try this and see if it works - //div[contains(.,'Standard')]. Can you share the URL of the application if it is public?

Hi Shawn, thanks a lot for your time, I tried below code with no luck
Dim ManageChannels As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".md-transition-in [name=""documentTypeName""]"))
ManageChannels.Click()
Dim builder1 As New Actions(driver)
Dim mouseOverAdmin As IAction = builder1.MoveToElement(ManageChannels).Build()
mouseOverAdmin.Perform()
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(.,'Standard')]")).Click()
I am able to click dropdown, it shows values (by searching it via documentTypeName)
but not able to click the value "Standard" which is the 2ns value in the drpd

I used css selector and it worked
By.CssSelector("md-option[title='Standard']"

I used css selector instead and it worked
By.CssSelector("md-option[title='Standard']"

